# Multiple Client Send and Receive voice using NAudio C# TCP Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to develope a Voice Chat window application using NAudio with multiple client, the problem is its not working or how can i send recorded voice to all the clients at same time and play on client side, then send the recorded voice of client and send it back to server.I am also using NetComm.dll to fetaure my application with Text Chat. Any help would be higly appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXD2B.jpg)

Comment: Are you familiar with such things as RTP and RTCP? The protocols are designed for the voice/video/media send/receive, synchronized according to timestamps associated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know a bit about RTP & RTCP but i never used it. Can you provide me some example for multiple client voice sending and receiving.

Answer (score -1):

```
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace NaudioVoiceChat
{
    public partial class Server: Form
    {
        #region Codes for NAudio ------->>>> This is for NAudio
        private BufferedWaveProvider bwp;
        WaveIn wi;
        WaveOut wo;
        public Server()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            #region Code for Naudio
            wo = new WaveOut();
            wi = new WaveIn();

            wi.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(wi_DataAvailable);

            bwp = new BufferedWaveProvider(wi.WaveFormat);
            bwp.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;

            wo.Init(bwp);
            wi.StartRecording();
        }

        void wi_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            bwp.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            server.SendData("Client-1", e.Buffer);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much but , No i think it won't work because you are not using WaveStream please try after then explain. I don't know how to use WaveStream but i am still searching...